# How to run rails migrations in app server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

my migrations are running on `db` server until now, but now, I want to
run then on `app`

deploy.rb

```
role :web, "192.168.110.54"
role :app, "192.168.110.54"
role :db, "192.168.110.50", :primary => true
```

If I change `role :app` to `:primary`, migrations why run on `app` server?

Note: I need to run migration on `app` server to change some files on `assests` folder.

Thank you!

Comment: Why not simply alter the IP address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's going to run the migrations on whatever is set as primary.